# Is there a way to stop/re-start ejb 3.1 automatic timer during runtime?

Tags: ejb, restart, schedule

I'm trying to use a simple automatic EJB schedule/timer. My code goes something like this:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class Scheduler {

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*/20", hour = "*"),
    private void fetchSomeData() {
        ...
    }

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*/5", hour = "*"),
    private void cleanThingsUp() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Is there a way to stop and restart automatic timers during the runtime? Please notice that I don't need to change the timeouts, I only need to stop and start the timers. All tutorials and examples I've found so far don't mention the stop/start concept at all (that is for the simple *@Schedule* timers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ejb Timers the closer ideas related to Start&Stop are Create&Cancel.

The posted code shows that you are using `Automatic Timer` which are very easy to create but, have a drawback: the Timer will be created automatically by Container only at deploy time. 
This leave you a small margin for Create operations.

However, once created, a Timer can be canceled calling the Timer.cancel() method.

e.g.:

```java
@Singleton
@Remote
public class MyTimer implements MyTimerRemote {

@Resource
TimerService timerService;

//MyTimer1, notice the info attribute
@Schedule (hour="*", minute="*", second="*", info="MyTimer1")
public void doSomthing(){
    System.out.println("Executing Timer 1");
}

//MyTimer2
@Schedule (hour="*", minute="*", second="*", info="MyTimer2")
public void doSomthing2(){
    System.out.println("Executing Timer 2");
}


//call this remote method with the Timer info that has to be canceled
@Override
public void cancelTimer(String timerInfo) {

    for (Timer timer: timerService.getTimers()) {
        if (timerInfo.equals(timer.getInfo())) {
            System.out.println("Canceling Timer: info: " + timer.getInfo());
            timer.cancel();
        }

    }   
}
```

And alternative is to create a `Programatic Timer`, this implies a little more code, but you can decide when create a particular Timer.

```java
//you can call this remote method any time 
@Override
public void createProgramaticTimer(String timerInfo) {
    System.out.println("Creating new PT: " + timerInfo);
    TimerConfig timerConf = new TimerConfig();
    timerConf.setInfo(timerInfo);
            //create a new programatic timer
    timerService.createIntervalTimer(1, 1000, timerConf); //just an example


}

@Timeout
public void executeMyTimer(Timer timer){
    System.out.println("My PT is executing...");

}
```

The Cancel operation remains the same as Automatic Timer.

Comment: But in this case , there can be only one Timeout method ( scheduled method ) per EJB right ? Do you have any alternative to the original code example ?

Comment: @NiranjanBhat The method annotated with Timeout can have an optional Timer argument. You can create more than one Timer, one for each method you want to schedule, and use the Timer.info property to identify which timer it is or which method you want to invoke from your Timeout method.